# In Unity, how to tell if it's the first time a game is being opened?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want a script to run,

whenever my game in Unity is opened for the first time.

Comment: Can you just use the local file system to record this information?

Comment: I don't know, how can i do that?

Comment: Check if the file `NotFirstRun` exists. If it does not exist then it is the first run, then create `NotFirstRun`. Running a second time will see that the `NotFirstRun` file exists. This is just a crude example. If you are persisting any other information locally already (such as game settings) then you can simply store a boolean with that mechanism.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `PlayerPrefs`. Check if key exist. If the key does not exist, return default value **1** and that is first time opening. Also, If this is first time opening set that key to **0** so that if will never return **1** again. So any value that is **not** **1** means that it is **not** the first time opening. In this example we can call the key `FIRSTTIMEOPENING`.

```
if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("FIRSTTIMEOPENING", 1) == 1)
{
    Debug.Log("First Time Opening");

    //Set first time opening to false
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("FIRSTTIMEOPENING", 0);

    //Do your stuff here

}
else
{
    Debug.Log("NOT First Time Opening");

    //Do your stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's simple.

You can use **PlayerPrefs.HasKey**

Example:

```
if(!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("firstTime")) //return true if the key exist
{
   print("First time in the game.");
   PlayerPrefs.SetInt("firstTime", 0); //to save a key with a value 0
   //then came into being for the next time
}
else
{
   print("It is not the first time in the game.");
  //because the key "firstTime"
}
```

Reference
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.HasKey.html

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

My code:

```css
public class LoadSaveManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int IsFirst; 

    void Start ()
    {
        IsFirst = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("IsFirst") ;
        if (IsFirst == 0) 
        {
            //Do stuff on the first time
            Debug.Log("first run");
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("IsFirst", 1);
        } else { 
            //Do stuff other times
            Debug.Log("welcome again!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: its my first post, sorry I will try to do better next time.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple

You can use **Time.realtimeSinceStartup;**

Example :

```
if(Time.realtimeSinceStartup < 10)
{ 
// first game opening
}else
{ 
// Welcome again
}
```

Reference : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-realtimeSinceStartup.html

Good luck!