# PlayerPrefs not working on Android nor Editor

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I have problems with PlayerPrefs on Android. I want my tutorial to show just one time so I wrote this code:

```
void Awake(){
        firstTime = false;
        hasPlayed = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("hasPlayed");
        if (hasPlayed == 0) {
            firstTime = true;
        } else {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("hasPlayed", 1);
            firstTime = false;
            PlayerPrefs.Save ();
        }
}
```

Once built and tested on phone, the apk doesn't create any folder on /data or whatever and consequently, the tutorial is showing everytime I run the game.

Comment: Try to log value of `hasPlayed`. You can also try to add second parameter to `GetInt("hasPlayed", 0);` to be sure that you get 0 as default value.

Comment: you just forgot the ", 0" on GetInt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PlayerPrefs.GetInt` takes another parameter you can use to return a value if the provided key does **not** exist. Check if `hasPlayed` key exist with default value of `0`. If the key does not exist, it will return that default value which is `0`.

If it returns `0`, set `hasPlayed` to `1` then play your tutorial. If it returns `1`, this means that the tutorial has been played before. Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36956927/3785314) question, but needs a little bit of modification.

Here is what it should look like:

```
void Start()
 {
     //Check if hasPlayed key exist. 
     if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("hasPlayed", 0) == 1)
     {
         hasPlayed();
     }
     else
     {
         //Set hasPlayed to true
         PlayerPrefs.SetInt("hasPlayed", 1);
         PlayerPrefs.Save();

         notPlayed();
     }
 }


 void hasPlayed()
 {
     Debug.Log("Has Played");
     //Don't do anything
 }

 void notPlayed()
 {
     Debug.Log("Not Played");
     //Play your tutorial
 }

 //Call to reset has played
 void resetHasPlayed()
 {
     PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("hasPlayed");
 }
```

Comment: @Cabrra Yes, `PlayerPrefs.HasKey` can be used. I actually used `PlayerPrefs.GetInt` on purpose so that this can be extended more. For example, most games have different levels with a tutorial in each level. The code above above can easily be extended to check which tutorial the player last played and which one to play next by adding `else if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("hasPlayed", 0) == 2)`. You can add as many tutorials as possible. `PlayerPrefs.HasKey` can't do this alone and will still require `PlayerPrefs.GetInt` in combination with it which makes code longer.

Comment: Also `GetInt(string key, int defaultValue);` performs `PlayerPrefs.HasKey` in the hood. it shortens the code. `PlayerPrefs.HasKey` is only needed if you just want to know if the key exist. In my case, I want to know if it exist and also get the value without using two functions.

Comment: Perfect, this statement: PlayerPrefs.GetInt("hasPlayed", 0) == 1 did the trick. Thanks a lot!