# Saving and then accessing saved file

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, save

How do I access file after I save it to persistent data path on android?
I looked all over my mobile files and I could not find the saved file.
When I ran debugging it pointed me to location that does not exist on my mobile?
storage/emulated/0

for code I use stream writer

```
string[][] output = new string[rowData.Count][];

for (int i = 0; i < output.Length; i++)
{
    output[i] = rowData[i];
}

int length = output.GetLength(0);
string delimiter = ",";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int index = 0; index < length; index++)
    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(delimiter, output[index]));


string filePath = getPath();

StreamWriter outStream = System.IO.File.CreateText(Application.persistentDataPath + 
    "/results" + settings.IdentificationNumber + ".csv");
outStream.WriteLine(sb);
outStream.Close();
```

I have no issue with getting this same code to work on pc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access the saved file, you first need to understand where `Application.persistentDataPath` points to. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44419658/location-of-application-persistentdatapath-in-a-build/44421935#44421935) post shows where it points to on most platforms.

For Andoid, that's at:

```
/Data/Data/com.<companyname>.<productname>/files
```

When SD card is available, this is at:

```
/storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.<companyname>.<productname>/files
```

It depends on the device model too. On some devices, it will not save on the SD card even when it is available.

---

Use `Debug.Log` or the `Text` component to log the `Application.persistentDataPath + "/results" + settings.IdentificationNumber + ".csv"` path. This will show you where to look for the saved file. If it's not saved on the SD card but on `/Data/Data/com.<companyname>.<productname>/files`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006315/how-to-access-data-data-folder-in-android-device) post for how to obtain the file on the `/Data/Data` folder.