# PlayerPrefs in Unity 3d doesn't work (sometimes)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Help, PlayerPrefs doesn't seem to work and can't figure out why.

I have a simple game that starts with:

```
void Start()
{

    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("IsReturningUser") == 1)
    {
        ScoreLabel.text = "Welcome back, friend!";
    }
    else
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("IsReturningUser", 1);
        ScoreLabel.text = "Welcome new player";
    }
```

When testing on my Android device from Unity Editor (build and run while connected) it works as intended - when I return to app second time it detects I'm returning.

However when I published the same code to Google Play store and clean installed from there, it never detects I'm a returning user when I return to app the second time.

Also strange, while it doesn't work on my Android phone, on my wife's phone installed from the Play Store it does detect as a returning user when she opens it the second time.

Any ideas?

Unity 5.3.6
My phone - Redmi Note 3, Android 6.0.1 MIUI 8.2 Stable 
Wife phone - OnePlusX

Comment: Oops. Just found a possible duplicate after adding answer. Will close question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had similar issue before.  I solved by adding a PlayerPrefs.Save() after calling the other PlayerPrefs.Set* methods.  This forces all writes to disk.

Comment: Thanks, that solves. I was exiting my phone by force closing which I guess skips the regular saving on exit. Now I save manually using this each time I set the values and that works.

Answer (score 3):

> it does detect as a returning user when she opens it the second time

Force it to save. Maybe that's the problem. After calling `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("IsReturningUser", 1);`, call `PlayerPrefs.Save()` to save it.

---

If that does not help at-all, give the `PlayerPrefs.GetInt` function a default value if the key does not exist like I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36956927/3785314). Just change `PlayerPrefs.GetInt("IsReturningUser") == 1` to `PlayerPrefs.GetInt("IsReturningUser", 0) == 1`.

---

Finally, if still not working, just use `File.WriteAllBytes` and save the file to `Application.persistentDataPath/yourFolderName`. You can find full example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40965645/what-is-the-best-way-to-save-game-state/40966346#40966346).