# Copy files from Resources/StreamingAssets to Application.persistentDataPath upon installation

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have `txt` file which contains data for my maps in game. Problem is that file is stored in `Application.persistentDataPath` so I can change it even from my android device (created map creator) so how can I include txt file which I created on my PC with basic maps and make it appear in `persistentDataPath` on my android device when I install application?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can put the file in the Resources folder from the Editor folder then read with the Resources API.

```
TextAsset txtAsset = (TextAsset)Resources.Load("textfile", typeof(TextAsset));
string tileFile = txtAsset.text;
```

You can check if this is the first time the app is running with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36956840/in-unity-how-to-tell-if-its-the-first-time-a-game-is-being-opened/36956927#36956927). After that you can copy the loaded data to the `Application.persistentDataPath`  directory.

---

The Resources folder is known to increase loading times. I suggest you **don't** use it but it's an option that's worth knowing.

Put the file in *StreamingAssets* folder then read it with the `WWW` or `UnityWebRequest` API and `Application.streamingAssetsPath` as the path then copy it to `Application.persistentDataPath`.

*Load from StreamingAssets*:

```
IEnumerator ReadFromStreamingAssets()
{
    string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "MyFile");
    string result = "";
    if (filePath.Contains("://") || filePath.Contains(":///"))
    {
        UnityEngine.Networking.UnityWebRequest www = UnityEngine.Networking.UnityWebRequest.Get(filePath);
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();
        result = www.downloadHandler.text;
    }
    else
        result = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);
}
```

then save it to persistentDataPath:

```
File.WriteAllText(Application.persistentDataPath + "data/MyFile.txt", result);
```

Comment: Storing file in Resources won't let you to change it. Actually it'll be readonly.

Comment: I never said you can modify it. OP wants to know how to put a file from the Editor and access it during run-time.

Answer (score 3):

You can store this file in your Resources folder and copy it to `Application.persistentDataPath` at your first app launch. Or read the file from Resources at first launch and create file with the same content in `Application.persistentDataPath`.