# Read from and write to text file from iOS device

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

From my iPad I try to save data to a text file and read it. The string from the textfile will be displayed in text field. On my MAC everything works fine, but if I try it on my iPad I always get the following error:

> DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path

This is the code I am using:

```
Text txtField

public void SaveDataToTextFile()
{
    using(StreamWriter saveData = new StreamWriter(Application.dataPath + "/Resources/TextFiles/textfile.txt"))
    {
        saveData.Write("Some Text");
        saveDate.Close();

        ReadSavedData();
    }
    // I also tried it with Application.persistenDataPath and Application.StreamingAssets
    // But with both solutions I received the error above
}

public void ReadSavedData()
{
    using(StreamReader readData = new StreamReader(Application.dataPath + "Resources/TextFiles/textfile.txt"))
    {
        var fileContent = savedData.ReadToEnd();
        var lines = fileContent.Split(new char[] { '\n' });

        foreach(var line in lines)
        {
            var savedDataString = line.Split(new char[] { '\n' });
            txtField.text = string.Join("\n", savedDataString.Skip(1));
        }
    }
}
```

I know this question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41326248/using-resources-folder-in-unity) and even to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45955427/copy-files-from-resources-streamingassets-to-application-persistentdatapath-upon) but non of them really helped me.

What do I have to change so that my iPad can write to and read from a text file?

### Edit

I could manage to read my text file with my iPad with the following code:

```
public void ReadSavedData()
{
    // Read dueDates TextFile:
    var textFile = Resources.Load<TextAsset>("TextFilePath/textFileName");
    var lines = textFile.text.Split(new char[] { '\n' });

    foreach(var line in lines)
    {
        var savedDataString = line.Split(new char[] { '\n' });
        txtField.text = string.Join("\n", savedDataString.Skip(1));
    }
}
```

But I am still not able to write into my text file.

Comment: You could do some checks to see if the resources folder and textfiles folders have been made

Comment: do you want to store data in build and write/read there or create in at runtime on your device?

Comment: I suggest googling the error message to look for suggestions. Also try debugging your code to figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Never** use simple string concatenation for system paths!

And note that especially

```
Application.dataPath + "Resources/TextFiles/textfile.txt"
```

without any separator makes no sense as this would be a file outside of the

```
Application.persistentDataPath
```

folder since it results in something like

```
/rootfolder/applicationfolderResources/TextFiles/textfile.txt
```

You need either a `\` or a `/` between them like e.g.

```
/rootfolder/applicationfolder/Resources/TextFiles/textfile.txt
```

So rather use [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) which uses the **correct path separators** according to the running OS.

```
Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "Resources", "TextFiles", "textfile.txt")
```

Then further a special note regarding `Resources`:

From Unity's own [Best Practices for the`Resources` folder](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/assets-resources-and-assetbundles#5c7f8528edbc2a002053b5a7)

> **Don't use it!**

There are a lot of reasons for this you can all find in the link but most importantly for your case: Both the `dataPath` and the `Resources` folder are **read-only** after a build!

So yes you *can* use it for loading stuff if you really insist but only using `Resources.Load`, not directly via the file path, how you already figured out - **but** you won't be able to write to it anyway.

Rather use the [`Application.persistentDataPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html) instead like e.g.

```
Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "TextFiles", "textFile.txt")
```

to store this file on the device - visible for the user though so you might want to use some sort of encryption.

---

Then it is still possible/probable that the folder `TextFiles` simply actually doesn't exist yet. So create it. I would also go through `File.Open` which is a bit more secure (e.g. create the file if it doesn't exist etc)

```
private string folderPath => Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "TextFiles");
private string filePath => Path.Combine(folderPath, "textFile.txt");

public void SaveDataToTextFile()
{
    if(!Directory.Exists(folderPath)
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
    }

    if(File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        File.Delete(filePath);
    }

    using(var fs = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))
    {
        using(war writer = new StreamWriter(fs))
        {
            writer.Write("Some Text");
        }
    }

    ReadSavedData();
}
```

And

```
public void ReadSavedData()
{
    if(!File.Exists(filePath)) return;

    using(var fs = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
    {
        using(var reader = new StreamReader(fs))
        {
            var fileContent = savedData.ReadToEnd();
            var lines = fileContent.Split(new char[] { '\n' });

            foreach(var line in lines)
            {
                var savedDataString = line.Split(new char[] { '\n' });
                txtField.text = string.Join("\n", savedDataString.Skip(1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it with `StreamWriter saveData = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "TextFiles", "textFile.txt"))` but I still get the same error message .. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: well does the folder exist?

Comment: When I run the app, it starts with `ReadSavedData()` which works fine and it uses the same folder path. So I think the folder exists.

Comment: See added section at the bottom

Comment: Now it works for one file .. thanks for that :) but unfortunately for a second file I get the following error even if I use your code `UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied`

Comment: What is the path you try and make sure according file is not opened anywhere else at the same time

Comment: This is the path which works `Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "TextFiles", "DueDates");` and with this path I get the error `Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "TextFiles", "Lubrication");` .. checked twice, the file is closed all the time

Comment: wrong information sorry, unfortunately I also get the error with the `DueDates` folder .. something thing from `using(var fs = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))` seems to throw the error

Comment: Did you try to add the file extension like ".txt"? Unfortunately I'm no iOs expert and code wise I don't see why this shouldn't work..

Comment: something still won't work, could find the mistake why I got the `UnautorizedAccessException` (used folderPath instead filePath) .. so I changed that, but now I get the `FileNotFoundException`

Comment: Well for the writer as in my answer it should be `FileMode.OpenOrCreate` in order to create the file if it doesn't exist ;)

Comment: I could manage it now .. thanks a lot, you helped me again a lot :)